# Android - remove traffic from Google maps in SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment

I load my map in:
    `public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {...`

I can't figure out how to turn off traffic layer. I tried `getMap().setTrafficEnabled(false);` but it doesn't seem to work.

Could someone help me understand how does it work? Thank you.

Comment: Where you put `getMap().setTrafficEnabled(false);`? Also use `getMapAsync()` because `getMap()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Aaron He! Deprecated `getMap()` was the issue. After refactoring my code to use `getMapAsync()` it works! Thanks again!